# Arrays and Pointers - difference in Lua FFI

Tags: c, pointers, lua, ffi, luajit

What is the difference between

```
myptr = ffi.new("int[1]")
```

and

```
myptr = ffi.new("int[0]")
```

As far as I understand it the first variant creates a pointer to an int which is the same as an array with one element.

1. Is the underlying structure a dynamically or statically allocated C array?
2. Since C does not make any bounds checking I assume its the same way here. So `myptr[20] = 11` works but will probably cause problems later?
3. Are the pointer and its associated value limited to their scope and will they be garbage collected?

Example:

```
function mod:myfunction()
     self.myptr = ffi.new("int[1]") 
     self.myptr[0] = 10
     otherptr = ffi.new("int[1]")
     otherptr[0] = 20
end

--somewhere later in the program

mynumber = mod.myptr[0]  --still valid?
othernumber = otherptr   --still valid?
```

4. Is the `int[0]` variant a zero length array? If so what is its use case?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: On LuaJIT `ffi=require'ffi'; p1, p0 = ffi.new"int[1]", ffi.new"int[0]"; print(ffi.sizeof(p1), ffi.sizeof(p0))` prints `4` and `0`.  So yes, it is a zero-size array.

Comment: Both answers on "still valid?" questions are "Yes".

Comment: `ffi.new` creates dynamically allocated C array

Comment: There is no bounds checking in LuaJIT, you can easily crash LuaJIT VM by allocating `p = ffi.new"int[10]"` and accessing `p[100000000]`.

Comment: Pointer and its associated value will be garbage collected outside the scope.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you very much. I like how seamlessly LuaJIT integrates C into lua. But on the other hand, it is sometimes hard to understand what happens under the hood.